# Exit Bash Mode?

Tags: linux, bash

I apologize for asking such a dumb question but my linux server is stuck in "bash" mode. When I log on through the terminal my command line looks like this:

```
-bash-3.2$
```

I cannot execute other commands because of this. If I type "exit" it closes the terminal window. How can I exit this bash mode so I can enter commands?!

Comment: You can't type anything? That looks like a naked bash prompt to me.

Comment: bash is a very common "shell" program for entering commands.  Perhaps you want a different shell?  What happens if you enter the commands that you want to enter?

Comment: When you say you "cannot execute other commands" what do you mean?  Where would you enter other commands if not into bash?  Or do you mean your graphical interface is not starting?

Comment: What mode do you *want* to be in?

Comment: Have you actually tried entering any commands (other than `exit`)?

Comment: Tell us, very precisely, what happens when attempt to "execute other commands." Tell us precisely what "other commands" you have tried. Do you receive an error message? Does the bash prompt reappear? Copy-and-paste a short terminal session if you can.

Comment: Im having the same problem, i changed the bashrc file on my server and now every time i log into it im in bash mode. I can do all i want in this bash mode but my current working directory doesn't appear on the left anymore. Which is bad.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson : see my answer below, it may help. Alternatively, alter your bashrc and set PS1 so that it includes either `\w` or `\W` (see bash manpage, 'PROMPTING' section for details). For example mine is set to `'[\u@\h \W]\$ '`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bash is a command line interpreter. It is one way to run commands on a linux system.

Are you saying that it isn't allowing you to run the commands you enter? What error or response is it giving when you run a command using bash?

Answer (score 2):

Try running the command `reset` it's possible you've screwed up the session.

Try running `tput setb 6` which changes the bgcolor to dark red. If it works then your settings are screwed up:

most likely if you have not been rooting around your system configs without proper knowledge of things: `rm ~/.bashrc`

`CTRL+ALT+F2` will pull you out of the X-Windows system and slam you into console. If things don't work properly there... you've screwed things up big time. Consult a NIX user forum for help with this topic as it isn't really a programming question.

http://www.unix.stackexchange.com/

Oh, and `tput setb 0` will restore your default background color.

Comment: It helped. I was playing around with chsh in my last session  to change from sh to bash. "reset" command resolved issue. Thanks for making my day start easy.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not the shell you want, you can always type in eg. `zsh`, `tcsh` or whatever inside this bash session to get into your shell of choice.

On a more permanent basis, your shell of choice is associated with your user-account. Examining `/etc/passwd`, you will find that the final item on each line defines which shell that user uses. Yours is likely to be set to `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`.

You are likely to have a GUI configuration tool, eg 'Users and Groups' on Ubuntu, where you can set your default shell.

Any changes to those settings take effect upon your next login.

Answer (score -1):

You should check two files in your own path : `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`

Make sure that they are in correct format.