# How to exit bash mode on server

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit Bash Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523431/exit-bash-mode)

Every time I enter my server I am now in Bash mode.

I don't want to be in bash mode because in it I don't have my current path on my left.

This question has already been asked here:
[Exit Bash Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523431/exit-bash-mode#comment16992733_10523431)
but OP accepted an answer that isn't really an answer.

I have already tried 'reset' and removing my .bashrc file.

Comment: Or may be you can just invoke csh!?

Comment: I just want to get back to normal mode.

Comment: What is the `normal mode` ? What actions would like to accomplish on the server?

Comment: normal mode is just that mode im in by default when i launch the terminal and until now, enter a server.

Comment: i would like to be able to do just all those actions that are done on the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Try "chsh -s /bin/sh" if you want to use sh. To see what your available shells are, "cat /etc/shells". You can also see what your current shell is by "echo $0" and simply "exec /bin/sh" will change shell for your session (not perm).

Comment: btw, `echo $0` better be `echo $SHELL`

Comment: it asks for authentication and doesn't accept my password. maybe this is something i need to take up with the hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

Changing default shell - /etc/passwd - for your unix account:

```
username:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/username:/bin/bash
                                        ^^^^^^^^^
```