# How to exit bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I ran this command

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/heroku-client/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

And since then I have been running in the bash shell. How do i get back to where I was? I don't even know exactly what shell I had previous. I am running Fedora 23.

Currently the shell looks like this,

```
bash: /home/pi/.bash_profileexport: No such file or directory
bash-4.3$
```

I think my question is similar to this post which didn't get an answer.
[Exit Bash Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523431/exit-bash-mode)
Thanks

Comment: Spoiler: You were running in bash before as well. The only difference is that now one of your startup scripts is broken.

Comment: This path does not exists `/home/pi/.bash_profileexport`

Comment: Just run `/usr/bin/vim /home/pi/.bashrc`. Then you'll get into [this issue](http://i.imgur.com/VOe71EA.png), but you can fix your `.bashrc` from there...

Answer (score 2):

I bet your ~/.bashrc used to have this on the last line:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

**but without a trailing newline**

When you appended a new line (export ...) to your .bashrc, it got appended to the end of the previous line since there was no newline line terminator:

```
. ~/.bash_profileexport PATH=...
#////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
#      old stuff  new stuff
```

Answer (score -3):

I had an FTP script that had this same problem. To solve it, I put the following at the end of my script.

```
 <<EOF
quit 0
EOF
```

Comment: If you don't know what the code does especially if it is doing anything helpful, then don't post an answer.

Comment: I tried /usr/bin/vim /home/pi/.bashrc .  (not sure if the final dot should be there, or if that is just end of a sentence.) anyway it brings me to VIM. What then?

Comment: My bad, I misread as How to exit TO bash. Some programs, such as LFTP, don't play nice and won't exit to bash unless you give it the keyboard commands I listed.